# Continuous Maps From $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to define a continuous 1-1 map from any open set $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I have trouble in giving a counter example here. I feel that it should not be possible but I may be wrong.

Comment: Think of some linear functionals...

Comment: You might as well take the open set $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I do not understand.

Comment: @Abhikumbale: For $n>1$ it is impossible. A non trivial projection has a non trivial kernel hence cannot be injective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not if $n > 1$.  Suppose such a function existed.  We may assume wlog $A$ is connected (else take a connected component).  Then $f(A)$ is an interval.  But removing a single interior point disconnects $f(A)$, while removing a single point of $A$ does not.  And the continuous image of a connected set is connected.